# Yii2 GridView shows "(not set)" if dataProvider contains GROUP BY and INNER JOIN

Tags: php, activerecord, gridview, yii2

I have show (only show, not compleate CRUD) the result of a query which is built as following:

```
SELECT SUM(a) AS ab, b, COUNT(*) as C
FROM x
INNER JOIN y
ON y.a = x.a
WHERE b=123
GROUP BY b
```

so I built this query with ActiveRecord in `SearchModel`s `search()` method.
In the model of table a I added a `hasOne()`-relation.

To display the data of this query, I'm using GridView. In it's columns array I use `y.b` and so on...

My problem: The columns from table x are displayed correct, but for every "joined column" from table y it displays (not set).
If I print the by ActiveRecord builded query, and execute it in my sql client, it displays all data.
 I guess this is depending on the Models `primaryKey()` function, but I can't change it to get the table work properly. Does somebody know a solution for my problem or why dataProvider/GridView takes care of the selected model's (in this case model of table x) `primaryKey()` method (or how to make dataProvider/GridView ignore the `primaryKey()`?

Comment: `ActiveRecord` require `relationName.property/columnName` to print related data and not table alias used in join.

Comment: The problem is, that the joined table not even shows up in the $dataProvider

Comment: Please show actual code (how did you build this query) - your abstract example hides actual problem.

Answer (score -1):

In model you should create relation method with relation model.
For example:

```
class Patient extends ActiveRecord
{

    public function getOrders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class, ['patient_id' => 'id']);
    }
}

class Order extends ActiveRecord
{
    public function getPatient()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Patient::class, ['id' => 'patient_id']);
    }
}
```

For access data:

```
// SELECT * FROM `patient` WHERE `id` = 1
$patient = Patient::findOne(1);
$orders = $patient->orders;
```

Comment: This is not the problem, as I mentioned I already did that and the join itself works fine. When I print the query in my searchModel and execute it in sql I get the right result.